# Unable to access backend after changing the default document root

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, ubuntu-14.04

I have hosted a website recently on `AWS ec2 ubuntu instance`. My directory structure consists of two folders:

```
back (consists of laravel 5.2)
front (consists of index.html,css and javascript files)
```

I am using laravel for the back end. Whenever I am accessing my website say 
www.abc.com I am getting the default ubuntu page. So, I had to manually go to www.abc.com/front/index.html. As a workaround, I changed the `Document root` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
from `/var/www/html` to `/var/www/html/front`. Everything works fine except for one thing - I am unable to access the back folder using the link `www.abc.com/back/public`.
What I think is happening would be I am now accessing www.abc.com/**front**/back/public.
What should be done now?

000-default.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/front

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: share your apache default.conf contens

Comment: @msonowal I added the default.conf

Comment: You need to make virtual hosts: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Don't your front and backs have different domains?

Comment: no, @El_Matella

Comment: So what are the urls you expect for the two projects?

Comment: its a single project consisting of front end and back end. I am running an ajax call from front end which inturn accesses the backend controller. The url for backend controller is wrong. @El_Matella

Comment: Well, then I really suggest you to make two different URLs for your projects... If you don't, you will have to put the back folder into the front folder, and this is, from my point of view, a really bad practice. 

If you want your front to be able to call your back on the same url as your front, you'll need to make a "proxy pass" to your backend. For example, calling "yourfront.com/proxy/api/foo" will respond with the response from "yourback.com/api/foo". You don't even need to use a public domain for the back

Answer (score 0):

replace your `DocumentRoot` to

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/front/public
```

and put these inside your conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html/front/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: but the public file is in back folder

Comment: than change it as per your path